# ACF & Bootstrap Gallery Shows Blank Slides

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I've been working on an ACF Gallery that uses the bootstrap carousel style.

I've got it to work but it seems to create an extra loop instead of closing it after the last image.

This is the code I have so far

```
<?php 
    $images = get_field('slider_portfolio');
    $divider = 2; 

    if( $images ): ?>

      <div id="mini-carousel2" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">            
        <div class="carousel-inner" style="max-height: 250px;min-height: 250px">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="row">
            <?php 
                $total = count( $images );
                $counter = 0;
                foreach( $images as $image ): 
                    $counter++; ?>

                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <a href="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>" class="fancybox img-<?php echo $counter; ?>" rel="mini" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="portfolio-gallery">
                    <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $image['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['title']; ?>" />
                </a>
                </div>
                <?php $current_position = $images->$image + 1; 

                    if (/* $image < $image->$total && */ $counter % $divider == 0) : ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                              <div class="row">                  
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#mini-carousel2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
 <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#mini-carousel2" role="button" data-slide="next">
 <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span></a></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help and advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the condition like this,

```
  if ( ($counter % $divider == 0) && $total > $counter) : ?>
```